# flutter problem : A RenderFlex overflowed by 248 pixels on the right

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-animation, flutter-test

### I am using three text in side a column, one text is long then I got this error "A RenderFlex overflowed by 248 pixels on the right."

I am using three text in side a column, one text field is long then I got this error "A RenderFlex overflowed by 248 pixels on the right." How to fix it?

[image]
This is m code.

```
import 'package:cwc/ApiManager/api_magager.dart';
import 'package:cwc/constants/constants.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class EVDetails extends StatefulWidget {
  final eventsListDetails;
  const EVDetails({Key? key, this.eventsListDetails}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<EVDetails> createState() => _EVDetailsState();
}

class _EVDetailsState extends State<EVDetails> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 20, 0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 10),
                  child:widget.eventsListDetails['image'] == null || widget.eventsListDetails['description'] =="" ?Image.asset(
                    'assets/video_cover.png',
                    height: 120,
                    width: 100,
                  ):Image.network(
                    imgBaseUrl+'${widget.eventsListDetails['image']}',
                    height: 120,
                    width: 100,
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(19, 15, 0, 0),
                  child: Flexible(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          '${widget.eventsListDetails['name']}',
                          style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                            fontSize: 18,
                            color: Color(0xff444444),
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,

                          ),maxLines: 1,
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Cancer, Diabetes and Dental \nProblems',
                          style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                            fontSize: 12,
                            color: Color(0xff8F9698),
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'For Champion Membership',
                          style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                            fontSize: 14,
                            color: Color(0xffC691D3),
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
               
              ],
            ),
            Text(
              'Event Description',
              style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                  fontSize: 18,
                  // color: Color(0xFFC691D3),
                  color: Color(0xff444444),
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 11,
            ),
            Text(
             "${widget.eventsListDetails['description']}",
              style:
                  GoogleFonts.poppins(fontSize: 13, color: Color(0xFF444444)),
              textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 24, 0, 0),
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color(0xffC691D3).withOpacity(0.2),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topRight: Radius.circular(10.0),
                      bottomRight: Radius.circular(10.0),
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(10.0),
                      bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10.0)),
                ),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Column( crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                'Start Date & Time',
                                style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                  fontSize: 12,
                                  color: Color(0xFF444444),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Text(
                                  "${formateDat(DateTime.parse(widget.eventsListDetails['startTime']))} at ${DateFormat("hh:mm a").format(DateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ").parseUTC("${widget.eventsListDetails['startTime']}").toLocal())} PT",
                                style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                  fontSize: 14,
                                  color: Color(0xFF444444),
                                ),
                              ),

                            ],
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 20,),
                          Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                'End Date & Time',
                                style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                  fontSize: 12,
                                  color: Color(0xFF444444),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Text(
                                "${formateDat(DateTime.parse(widget.eventsListDetails['endTime']))} at ${DateFormat("hh:mm a").format(DateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ").parseUTC("${widget.eventsListDetails['endTime']}").toLocal())} PT",

                                style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                  fontSize: 14,
                                  color: Color(0xFF444444),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 5, 10, 2),
                                child: Row(
                                  children: [
                                    Row(
                                      children: [
                                        Icon(
                                          Icons.schedule,
                                          color: Color(0xFFC691D3),
                                        ),
                                        SizedBox(
                                          width: 2,
                                        ),
                                        Text(
                                          '${widget.eventsListDetails['duration']} mins',
                                          style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                              fontSize: 14,
                                              color: Color(0xFFC691D3)),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: 5,
                                    ),
                                    Row(
                                      children: [
                                        Icon(
                                          Icons.online_prediction,
                                          color: Color(0xFFC691D3),
                                        ),
                                        SizedBox(
                                          width: 2,
                                        ),
                                        Text(
                                          '${widget.eventsListDetails['eventMode']}',
                                          style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                              fontSize: 14,
                                              color: Color(0xFFC691D3)),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Spacer(),
                      Image.asset(
                        'assets/calender.png',
                        height: 120,
                        width: 120,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
formateDat(DateTime date) {
  final DateFormat formatter = DateFormat.MMM();
  String formatted = formatter.format(date);
  formatted = "${formatted} " +"${date.day}";
  var week = DateFormat('EEEE').format(date);
  var we = week[0] + week[1] + week[2];
  return "$we, " + formatted;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Column(
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
                 Expanded(
                Text(
                  ' {widget.eventsListDetails[index][ name ]}',
                )),
                Expanded(Text('Cancer,Diabetes and Dental Problems')),
                Expanded(Text(
                  " {widget.eventsListDetails[index]['description']}ex]['description']}",
                ),)
              ],
            ),
```

Comment: No Its Not working

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its help to you. Put your Column Inside Expanded Widget:

```
 Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Container(
          padding:EdgeInsets.all(5),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.orange.shade200,
            border:Border.all(color:Colors.black,),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(12.0),
          ),),
          child: Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Image.network(
                'https://miro.medium.com/max/1400/1*-6WdIcd88w3pfphHOYln3Q.png',
                width: 100,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 10,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Column(//put this column inside Expanded widget
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      ' {widget.eventsListDetails[index][ name ]}',
                    ),
                    Text('Cancer,Diabetes and Dental Problems'),
                    Text(
                      " {widget.eventsListDetails[index]['description']}ex]['description']}",
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 10),
        Text('Event Description'),
        SizedBox(height: 10),
        Text(
            'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.'),
      ],
    ),
```

Your result screen-> [image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution,

```
Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Container(
                width: 150,
                height: 150,
                color: Colors.grey,
              ),
              const SizedBox(width: 10,),
              Expanded(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text('Lorem ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.')
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          )
```