# Flutter Vertical and Horizontal overflow issue

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, overflow, flutter-web, flutter-desktop

I'm trying to create a fully responsive design. I'm facing the overflow issue **when I resize my screen from bottom to top(Vertically) or top to bottom** in desktop view.  And I face horizontal responsiveness overflow from right and bottom sides, if I shrink the window size to much. There are two things 1rst **I think the issue will be resolve with scrollbars, but I'm not able to add scrollbars**. 2nd I would like to have a solution(or method, or widgets) for all type of responsiveness(horizontal and vertical) ,as soon as possible.

**Normal Desktop View**

[image]

**Bottom Over Flow Issue when I resize Vertically**
[image]

**Normal Mobile View**

[image]

**Vertical and Horizontal Over Flow Issue after Resizing**

[image]

**Flutter Doctor**

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.318], locale en-PK)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Professional 2022 17.0.5)
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
[√] VS Code (version 1.64.0)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability

• No issues found!
```

**Web_Screen Code**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
import 'package:g_res_p/colors/colors.dart';
import 'package:g_res_p/widgets/search.dart';
import 'package:g_res_p/widgets/webButtons/search_button1.dart';
import 'package:g_res_p/widgets/webButtons/translation_btn.dart';
import 'package:g_res_p/widgets/webButtons/upper_web_footer.dart';
import 'package:g_res_p/widgets/webButtons/web_footer.dart';

class WebScreenLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  const WebScreenLayout({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
        elevation: 0,
        actions: [
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: const Text(
              'Gmail',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: primaryColor,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            width: 10,
          ),
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: const Text(
              'Images',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: primaryColor,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            width: 10,
          ),
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: SvgPicture.asset(
              'assets/images/more-apps.svg',
              color: primaryColor,
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            width: 10,
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0).copyWith(
              right: 10,
            ),
            child: MaterialButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              color: const Color(
                0xff1A73EB,
              ),
              child: const Text(
                'Sign in',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: size.height * 0.25,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Column(
                    children: const [
                      Search(),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 20,
                      ),
                      SearchButton1(),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 20,
                      ),
                      TranslationButtons(),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Column(
                    children: const [
                      UpperWebFooter(),
                      Divider(
                        height: 1,
                        color: dividerColor,
                      ),
                      WebFooter(),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Mobile_Screen Code**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
import 'package:g_res_p/colors/colors.dart';
import 'package:g_res_p/widgets/mobile/mobiel_footer.dart';
import 'package:g_res_p/widgets/search.dart';
import 'package:g_res_p/widgets/webButtons/search_button1.dart';
import 'package:g_res_p/widgets/webButtons/translation_btn.dart';
import 'package:g_res_p/widgets/webButtons/upper_web_footer.dart';

class MobileScreenLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  const MobileScreenLayout({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
        elevation: 0,
        leading: IconButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          icon: const Icon(
            Icons.menu,
            color: Colors.grey,
          ),
        ),
        title: SizedBox(
          width: size.width * 0.34,
          child: const DefaultTabController(
            length: 2,
            child: TabBar(
              indicatorColor: blueColor,
              unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
              labelColor: blueColor,
              indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
              tabs: [
                Tab(
                  text: 'All',
                ),
                Tab(
                  text: 'Images',
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: SvgPicture.asset(
              'assets/images/more-apps.svg',
              color: primaryColor,
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            width: 10,
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0).copyWith(
              right: 10,
            ),
            child: MaterialButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              color: const Color(
                0xff1A73EB,
              ),
              child: const Text(
                'Sign in',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: size.height * 0.25,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Column(
                    children: const [
                      Search(),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 20,
                      ),
                      SearchButton1(),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 20,
                      ),
                      TranslationButtons(),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Column(
                    children: const [
                      UpperWebFooter(),
                      Divider(
                        height: 1,
                        color: dividerColor,
                      ),
                      MobileFooter(),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use Scrollable widget for `Desktop View`, and for MobileView, you can use `Wrap` widget.

Comment: I tried but I failed to implement Scrollable widget. I don't know the right place and way to implement Scrollable widget with conditions. It would be very helpful if you can implement those widgets in the code. And footer and text buttons are already Wraped by Wrap widget.

Comment: If you get horizontal overflow error then refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68646487/13997210) and if you get Vertical overflow error then Try to add your Inside Row widgets wrap it with `Expanded` or `Flexible` refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68463935/13997210) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68559619/13997210) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68444861/13997210) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70743585/13997210) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70743585/13997210) hope its helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

use SingleChildScrollView:

```
body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child:...
      )
```

Comment: when I use "SingleChildScrollView(child:Column...)" the screen goes blank and the terminal goes infinitely error loop...

Comment: what error message exactly?

Comment: `Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/mouse_tracker.dart': Failed assertion: line 201 pos 12: '!_debugDuringDeviceUpdate': is not true.`

Comment: `[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: Cannot hit test a render box with no size.`

Comment: I used the same code but it didn't show me any error !!! have you used hot reload or hot restart?

Comment: Yes I even restarted vscode. But the errors are same. `Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#aa260 relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT
The Flutter DevTools debugger and profiler on Windows is available at: http://127.0.0.1:9101?uri=http://127.0.0.1:57673/6nThFfRHX0o=/`

Comment: btw Ma Jeed, the code that I provided here ,are only 2 dart files, and there are almost 10,12 dart files in my project. Also I'm running the code on windows, did you run the code on windows or chrome?

Comment: I used chrome, instead of SingleChildScrollView I used a ListView like this : ListView(
            children: [ SizedBox(...) , Column(...)])

Comment: did u used `shrinkwrap:true` in listview?

Comment: yes i did : shrinkWrap : true,

Comment: let me try this ass well

Comment: `[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value`. This the error after using `ListView(childeren:[SizedBox(),Column()])`.And on web screen the body has gone blank. Same for chrome and windows.

Comment: I guess the problem is in one of your files

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241872/discussion-between-ma-jeed-and-m-nouman).

Comment: which files you didn't use from my code when you run on your side?

Comment: I didn't use any of your files except the Web_Screen Code and I replace all the widget with  Icons