# Dart Flutter overflowing words to bottom line

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm building a language application. The application is as follows:

[image]

There is "How's your day going?" he is writing. But there is an overflow problem because it does not fit.

I want it to automatically go to the bottom line if it overflows. How can I do that?

Codes:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:getwidget/getwidget.dart';

class selamlasmaLearn_2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<selamlasmaLearn_2> createState() => _selamlasmaLearn_1State();
}

class _selamlasmaLearn_1State extends State<selamlasmaLearn_2> {
    final CarouselController _controller = CarouselController();

  List<wordAndMeaning> wordsList = [
    wordAndMeaning("How's it going?", "Nasıl gidiyor?", false),
    wordAndMeaning("How's your day?", "Günün nasıldı?", false),
    wordAndMeaning("How's your day going?", "Günün nasıl gidiyor?", false),
    wordAndMeaning("Nice to see you", "Seni görmek güzel", false),
    wordAndMeaning("It's been a while", "Görüşmeyeli uzun zaman oluyor", false),

  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.amber[500],
        bottomOpacity: 0,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
        title: Text("Selamlama", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
      body: Builder(builder: (context) {
        final double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 160;
        return Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: CarouselSlider(
                carouselController: _controller,
                options: CarouselOptions(
                  height: height,
                  viewportFraction: 1.0,
                  enlargeCenterPage: false,
                ),
                items: wordsList.map((wordAndMeaning word) {
                  return Expanded(
                    child: Builder(
                      builder: (BuildContext context) {
                        return Container(
                          width: 45, // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<!!!!!!!
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.amber),
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                            children: [
                              Column(
                                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                children: [
                                  
                                  if (word.showMeaning) ...[
                                    Text(word.meaning,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 200, color: Colors.white)),
                                  
                                  Text(word.word,
                                      style:
                                          TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white)),
                                  
                                  ],
                              
                                  if (!word.showMeaning) ...[
                                    Text(word.word,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 45, color: Colors.white)),
                                  ],
                                  
                                ],
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(
                                width: 10,
                              ),
                              IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(Icons.remove_red_eye_sharp),
                                color: Colors.white,
                                iconSize: 25,
                                onPressed: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    word.showMeaning = !word.showMeaning;
                                  });
                                },
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(20)),
                  color: Colors.amber[300],
                  
              ),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          
                        ),
                        width: 130,
                        height: 60,
                        child: Container(
                          child: GFButton( 
                            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
                            text: "Geri", textStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white, fontSize: 24),
                            // borderi kapatma:
                            onPressed: () => _controller.previousPage(
                                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
                                curve: Curves.easeInCirc,
                              ),
                            size: GFSize.LARGE,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 10,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 10,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        ),
                        width: 130,
                        height: 60,
                        child: Container(
                          child: GFButton(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
                            text: "İleri", textStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white, fontSize: 24),
                            onPressed: () => _controller.nextPage(
                                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
                                curve: Curves.easeInCirc,
                              ),
                            size: GFSize.LARGE,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        );
        
      }),
    );
  }
}

class wordAndMeaning {
  String word;
  String meaning;
  bool showMeaning;

  wordAndMeaning(this.word, this.meaning, this.showMeaning);
}
```

The size of the text is determined in line 54. I've also commented out the code that determines the size.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Flexible` or `Expanded` widgets.

```
Expanded(
  child: Text("How's it going?"),
)
```

**OR**

```
Flexible(
  child: Text("How's it going?"),
)
```

Both approaches have their own advantages, But a `Flexible` widget is preferable as it renders the widget as per Text can occupy.

Answer (score 0):

Add your Text widget insede Expanded or Flexible Widget

```
Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Text(
            'Hello, World!Hello, World!Hello, World!Hello, World!Hello, World!Hello, World!Hello, World!Hello, World!Hello, World!Hello, World!Hello, World!Hello, World!Hello, World!Hello, World!Hello, World!Hello, World!Hello, World!Hello, World!Hello, World!Hello, World!Hello, World!',
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

Result Screen-> [image]

Try to add your Inside Row widgets wrap it with `Expanded` or `Flexible` refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68463935/13997210) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68559619/13997210) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68444861/13997210) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70743585/13997210) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70743585/13997210) hope its helpful to you