# Flutter : Right overflowed by 70 pixels

Tags: flutter

i m new to flutter and am trying to make a Responsive  app , i have a textfield and i wanted to add a dropdown list next to it it s working but it shows a error " right overflowed by 150 pixels" even tho i m using the Expanded widget in the child . the error is in both dropdownlists
thank you for ur help in advance
[image]

```
import '../Classes/demandes.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import '../data/menu_item.dart';
import '../Classes/menu.dart';
import '../data/logout.dart';

class Demandes extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _demande createState() => _demande();
}

class _demande extends State<Demandes> {
  String dropdownValue = 'Assets';
  String dropdownValue1 = 'Locations';

  Future<Demandes?> submitData(String description, ASSETNUM, location,
      DESCRIPTION_LONGDESCRIPTION) async {
    var respone = await http.post(
        Uri.parse(
            'http://9080/maxrest/rest/mbo/sr/?_lid=azizl&_lpwd=max12345m&_format=json'),
        body: {
          "description": description,
          "ASSETNUM": ASSETNUM,
          "location": location,
          "DESCRIPTION_LONGDESCRIPTION": DESCRIPTION_LONGDESCRIPTION,
        });
    var data = respone.body;
    print(data);
    if (respone.statusCode == 201) {
      dynamic responseString = respone.body;
      azizFromJson(responseString);
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
          .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Demande de service Cree")));
    } else
      return null;
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
        .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("error")));
    return null;
  }

  late Demandes? _demandes;
  TextEditingController descriptionController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController ASSETNUMController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController locationController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController DESCRIPTION_LONGDESCRIPTIONController =
      TextEditingController();

  Widget DescriptionTextField() {
    return TextField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        // labelText: "Description",
        border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
      ),
      controller: descriptionController,
    );
  }

  Widget AssetTextField() {
    return TextField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        //   labelText: "Asset",
        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
      ),
      controller: ASSETNUMController,
    );
  }

  Widget DeatialsTextField() {
    return TextField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        //  labelText: "Details",
        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
      ),
      maxLines: 10,
      controller: DESCRIPTION_LONGDESCRIPTIONController,
    );
  }

  Widget LocationTextField() {
    return TextField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        //  labelText: "Location",
        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
      ),
      controller: locationController,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Creation Demande de service'),
          actions: [
            PopupMenuButton<MenuItem>(
              onSelected: (item) => onSelected(context, item),
              itemBuilder: (context) =>
                  [...MenuItems.itemsFirst.map(buildItem).toList()],
            )
          ],
        ),
        body: ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),

          // ignore: prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables
          children: [
            ListTile(
              title: Text("Description"),
            ),
            DescriptionTextField(),
            ListTile(
              title: Text("Details"),
            ),
            DeatialsTextField(),
            ListTile(title: Text("Asset")),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: AssetTextField(),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  width: 20,
                ),
                Expanded(
                    child: DropdownButton<String>(
                  value: dropdownValue,
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
                  elevation: 16,
                  style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                  underline: Container(
                    height: 2,
                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 140, 255),
                  ),
                  onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                    setState(() {
                      dropdownValue = newValue!;
                    });
                  },
                  items: <String>[
                    'Assets',
                    '100014 moteur 3',
                    '100027 Système de freinage 1',
                    '12500 Overhead Crane #2',
                    '13110 Feeder System',
                    '13120 Bottom Sealing System',
                    '13130 Stripper System',
                    '13140 Conveyor System- Pkg. Dept.',
                    '13141 Elevator Rails And Drainpan Assembly',
                    '13142 Carton Escapement Assembly #2',
                    '13143 Chain Wash Assembly',
                  ].map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                      value: value,
                      child: Text(value),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                )),
              ],
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text("Location"),
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: LocationTextField(),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  width: 20,
                ),
                Expanded(
                    child: DropdownButton<String>(
                  value: dropdownValue1,
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
                  elevation: 16,
                  style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                  underline: Container(
                    height: 2,
                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 140, 255),
                  ),
                  onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                    setState(() {
                      dropdownValue1 = newValue!;
                    });
                  },
                  items: <String>[
                    'Locations',
                    '100014 moteur 3',
                    '10002  7 Système de freinage 1',
                    '12500 Overhead Crane #2',
                    '13110 Feeder System',
                    '13120 Bottom Sealing System',
                    '13130 Stripper System',
                    '13140 Conveyor System- Pkg. Dept.',
                    '13141 Elevator Rails And Drainpan Assembly',
                    '13142 Carton Escapement Assembly #2',
                    '13143 Chain Wash Assembly',
                  ].map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                      value: value,
                      child: Text(value),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                )),
              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              width: 20,
            ),
            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10)),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: (() async {
                String description = descriptionController.text;
                String ASSETNUM = ASSETNUMController.text;
                String location = locationController.text;
                String DESCRIPTION_LONGDESCRIPTION =
                    DESCRIPTION_LONGDESCRIPTIONController.text;
                Demandes? data = await submitData(description, ASSETNUM,
                    location, DESCRIPTION_LONGDESCRIPTION);
                setState(() {
                  _demandes = data;
                });
              }),
              child: Text("submit "),
            )
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show a screenshot pls ?

Comment: where exactly i cant put screenshots yet

Comment: here you go i edited it

Comment: Try to add your Inside Row widgets wrap it with `Expanded` or `Flexible` refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68463935/13997210) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68559619/13997210) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68444861/13997210) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70743585/13997210) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70743585/13997210) hope its helpful to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok the only thing that you have to write is this :

```
Expanded(
   child: DropdownButton<String>(
      value: dropdownValue,
      isExpanded: true, // this 
      [...]
   ),
),
```

Like the documentation say :

> Set the dropdown's inner contents to horizontally fill its parent.
>
> By default this button's inner width is the minimum size of its
> contents. If [isExpanded] is true, the inner width is expanded to fill
> its surrounding container.